# how stackoverflow knows that I am me?

Tags: support, login

I noticed that once one gets on the website, one is automatically log in. Even after emptied my cache, my cookies and my LSO cookies, I am still recognized.
So I ask : how stackoverflow.com can recognize me without a doubt ? Have you Guys, got some NSA files about my location and internet identity ?

Thank you

Comment: [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). Clear that, and you won't be logged in automatically again.

Comment: They are watching you through your webcam...

Comment: @shadow Thanks ! I didn't see that before.

Comment: Sure @John, that's what we're here for. :)